# xcode 5 how to delete target

Tags: ios, xcode

In xcode 5, there is no option for creating unittest project while creating project. I want to delete the unitest target after the project is created.

There is no target list I can right click, I can chose target to edit but not able to delete. I know it should be really basic and really simple. But I google it and play around for almost half day, still confused.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried selecting the target and then using the delete or backspace key?

Answer (score 127):

You probably just hid this menu with the arrow in it:

[image]

Comment: Really appreciate! It is exactly what I need. This small button cost me half day

Comment: Ha! I thought that was a "play" button.

Comment: @BenFlynn - Xcode 5 hidden feature - "coding playlist" - startup idea ;)

Answer (score 28):

In Xcode 6 its different as to how to delete the target. See these pics.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't believe Xcode interface that we have to even have a page on s/o dedicated to this... thanks for this!